# Calculate the mean of specific cells of multiple csv files

Tags: csv, mean

I have multiple csv files, all with the same format. There are columns with an object and columns with their values.
For example:

```
.....Animals   |   Age  ....

      dog           2

      cat           4

      dog           6 

       ....etc.
```

And I want to calculate the mean age of all the dogs in all the csv files.
Which language will be easier to use for this calculation? Any help regarding the implementation?

Comment: Please make you question more specific. pick a language first, then figure out what context you need to do the calculation in.

Comment: My main question is regarding the language because I cant pick one. I don't know which language is good for this kind of problems

Comment: Any language can do it. but is it in a web app you might run it on a node server or php. native you might run java, c#, c++, VB.

Comment: I'd look at R for something like this

Comment: No its not a web app. Its locally. I have a lot of csv files and I want to perform these calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it with Java and openCSV library.